# How to delete an element of a list in list in Python?

Tags: python

I know how to remove an element in a list (e.g using .remove() method). But how to remove an element of a list in list?

In the attached picture, there are two elements [0.0,inf] in the first two lists of the whole list that I want to remove.

Could anyone give me a hint or solution to deal with this? Thanks a lot in advance[image]

Comment: Are these lists all happen to be in the last position or in random positions? If so, just *loop* and get rid of *last* sublist.

Comment: All the last position of each "inner" list is [0.0, inf].

Comment: Please [don't post code/errors/data as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach, assuming these two lists are all in the last positions:

Using the lsts[:] syntax is to assign the result back to original lists.

```py
# List Comprehension to loop and get rid of last item.

lsts[:] = [sub[:-1] for sub in lsts]  #lsts is your original lists.
```

Comment: Why use `lsts[:]` for in-place replacement but generate new instances for the sublists ?  Seems a bit inconsistent to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop thhrough the sublists and use `remove` (or `pop(-1)` if the values to remove are always present and always last in the sublist):

```
inf = float('inf')
M = [ [ [0.0254667978733778, 0.007302640238776803],
        [0.0287586972117424, 0.011580605059862137],
        [0.03155571571551263, 0.009782221401110291],
        [0.025357562582939863, 0.01641937019303441],
        [0.021751650143414736, 0.02018721727654338],
        [0.03572308551520109, 0.009355328045785427],
        [0.013055980205535889, 0.03486280515789986],
        [0.023708383552730083, 0.02596351783722639],
        [0.012890402227640152, 0.03700174391269684],
        [0.0, inf]],
      [ [0.022236602380871773, 0.010978079866617918],
        [0.02360635856166482, 0.012177807278931141],
        [0.025357562582939863, 0.01641937019303441],
        [0.03572308551520109, 0.009355328045785427],
        [0.013055980205535889, 0.03486280515789986],
        [0.02809232717845589, 0.020170105039142072],
        [0.022387880366295576, 0.0260826856829226],
        [0.0254667978733778, 0.02442534826695919],
        [0.01855770405381918, 0.031348743475973606],
        [0.0, inf]
      ]
    ]
```

if the item to remove is not always there or not always last you can use remove in a loop:

```
toRemove = [0.0,inf]
for sublist in M: 
    if toRemove in sublist:       
        sublist.remove(toRemove)
```

If the item to remove is always last and always present, you can use pop(-1):

```
for sublist in M: sublist.pop(-1)
```

output (content of M):

```
[[[0.0254667978733778, 0.007302640238776803], 
  [0.0287586972117424, 0.011580605059862137], 
  [0.03155571571551263, 0.009782221401110291], 
  [0.025357562582939863, 0.01641937019303441], 
  [0.021751650143414736, 0.02018721727654338], 
  [0.03572308551520109, 0.009355328045785427], 
  [0.013055980205535889, 0.03486280515789986], 
  [0.023708383552730083, 0.02596351783722639], 
  [0.012890402227640152, 0.03700174391269684]], 
 [[0.022236602380871773, 0.010978079866617918], 
  [0.02360635856166482, 0.012177807278931141], 
  [0.025357562582939863, 0.01641937019303441], 
  [0.03572308551520109, 0.009355328045785427], 
  [0.013055980205535889, 0.03486280515789986], 
  [0.02809232717845589, 0.020170105039142072], 
  [0.022387880366295576, 0.0260826856829226], 
  [0.0254667978733778, 0.02442534826695919], 
  [0.01855770405381918, 0.031348743475973606]]]
```